# I can't add MPAndroidChart in gradle 7.0.0 and android studio 2020.3.1

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle

[Could not find com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjmTX.png)

Comment: do you setup gradle repositories {
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
}

Answer (score 0):

adding maven   `maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }` in `settings.gradle` it will work with you fine